# Hibernate hql and session management

Tags: hibernate, hql, sessionfactory

this week i learned to program hibernate and i'm not shure if my approach is the right. I read a lot of articles and every hibernate article looked a bit different. I'm using Hibernate 4, is this the right approach to get Data from my database? It's currently working, but im not shure if this is the best way :) am i missing something? Are there better/cleaner ways to get the data?

```
    @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<UserFigures> getKeyFigure(int userId) {

    Session session = getSessionFactoryDw().openSession();

    String hql = "from Figures " +
                "where UserID = :userId ";

    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    List<UserFigures> res = query.list();
    session.close();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main problems with your code are the non-respect of Java naming conventions, the lack of transaction, and the poor session handling code.

Given your usage of @Autowired, I guess you're using Spring. You should thus use Spring session and transaction management to have a contextual session (i.e. use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` instead of `sessionFactory.openSession()`), tied to the current Spring declarative transaction.

The Spring documentation has a whole [chapter dedicated to Hibernate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#orm-hibernate). Read it.

Also, `Figures` should be named `Figure`.